# Регистрация номера телефона в Python (aiogram 3.x)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

каким образом сделать механизм регистрация номера телефона по формату, т.е человек водит номер телефона и он обязательно должен быть такого формата (+7xxxxxxxxx) - иначе бот выдаст пользователю ошибку о том, что номер телефона был веден неверно

```
@router.message(F.text.lower() == "пройти регистрацию")
async def reg_user(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Register.RegName)
    await message.answer("Введите Ваше имя")


@router.message(Register.RegName)
async def reg_user_2(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(RegName=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Register.RegPhone)
    await message.answer("Введите номер телефона\n"
                         "Формат телефона: +7xxxxxxxxx")


@router.message(Register.RegPhone)
async def reg_user_phone(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(RegPhone=message.text)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f"Спасибо, регистрация завершена\nВаше имя: {data['RegName']}\nВаш номер: {data['RegPhone']}")
    await state.clear()
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку на формат номера телефона.

Comment: Эээ, а для чего просить пользователя указать номер телефона, если можно просто кнопкой запросить контакт? И он всегда будет в едином формате, нежели его будут указывать вручную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

tel=input("Введити номер телефона в формате +7XXXXXXXXXX  ")
if re.match('\+7\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d',tel):
    print("Правильный телефон ",tel)
else:
    print("Неправильный телефон", tel)
```

---

```
Введите номер телефона в формате +7XXXXXXXXXX  +71234567788
Правильный телефон  +71234567788

Введите номер телефона в формате +7XXXXXXXXXX  8 132 456 78 88
Неправильный телефон 8 132 456 78 88
```

Comment: почему бы не использовать `'\+7\d{10}'` как шаблон ? выглядит короче и читается быстрее